# Google App Engine Java development on IntelliJ?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

Annoyingly, Google App Engine has become another one of those projects where they only release plugins for Eclipse (like Spring Webflow) and I just much prefer IntelliJ. Can you run the local test environment successfully with IntelliJ? And debug/deploy a local or live application? If so, are there any features missing that are in the Eclipse version?

Comment: Do you have any additional info on this or what worked for you ? The accepted answer does not work with the community (free) version of IntelliJ anymore, and the method described in the other answer is a kludge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IntelliJ plugin for Google App Engine integration http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=4254

Comment: At some point, this plugin ceased to work with the Community Edition.

Comment: Still missing from community version in July of 2014.

Comment: Still missing from community version in May of 2016

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can configure IntelliJ to run the local app engine.  There is a [blog](http://www.gridshore.nl/2009/04/08/java-on-google-app-engine-with-intellij/) entry with step by step instructions.

The differences between the Eclipse plugin

- Doesn't launch browser
- Didn't auto magically run the data nucleus enhance
- No deploy to Google button.

You can work around the data nucleus enhance by making your run target depend on the datanucleusenhance ant task.  The other two were so minor, I haven't bothered to automate them.

Comment: Thanks, this sort of works, whereas the plugin mentioned in the accepted answer describes doesn't work with the community edition of IntelliJ  anymore.