# Google app engine Java SDK 1.9.7 plugin for Intellij?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I know the community version (free) version seemed to have a well integrated version of the plugin previously (like 4 years ago?) : [Google App Engine Java development on IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815499/google-app-engine-java-development-on-intellij)

however, i can't get that downloaded plugin to work with my current version of Intellij and also google app engine java sdk 1.9.7.

where is the silver bullet that i'm looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ supports App Engine by default since version 9.

All you have to do is create a Maven project with an App Engine dependency, and Intellij will pick it up.

[You can find the official documentation on Maven and App Engine here.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven)